# What is intention of making a function "const"

Tags: c++, function, constants

Like this,

```
bool isEmpty() const { return root==NULL; }
```

This is isEmpty function, test if the BST is empty or not.

Comment: http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/oop-memberfuncs/constmemberfuncs.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It indicates that the function does not modify any of the members of that class.

Usually, the Interface/declaration(through header file) is made available to the users of the class/functions and not the implementation,So the `const` makes it clear to the user that the function does not modify any members.

Adding the `const` also makes the user of the function aware that this `const` member functions should be used when you have an `const` object.You cannot call normal member function on a `const` object of that class,it will result in a compiler error.

That is the reason that the function is marked `const` even if it is empty.It indicates a contract between the function implementer and the user of the function.

Comment: Also that it is callable if you have a const version of the object. Non const functions are not callable from a const instance.

Comment: @Als you are saying 'const member functions can only be called on a const object of that class'. That is not true: const member functions can be invoked on non-const objects too :) The other way around however is not possible

Comment: @TomKnapen: Ah,Ofcourse,English can play tricks sometimes(especially to non native English speakers like me) :). Thanks I corrected that typo.

Comment: If you have a const version of an object and you are calling a method of that object, then if the compiler complains that there is no such function, it is because that method is not const.

Answer (score 2):

When a function is marked as `const`, the function can be invoked on a `const` instance of the class. Invoking a non-`const` function on a `const` object will lead to a compile-time error.

Basically, you want to mark all functions that don't change the state of your object as `const`; this way, you can use `const` as an immutability declaration and the compiler will enforce it for you, by making sure you can only invoke the `const` functions.

You can invoke `const` functions on a non-`const` instance no problem.

Answer (score 0):

It tells the compiler that the function will not modify the state of the class. Also, const functions are the only functions allowed to be called on const objects.

Answer (score 0):

It indicates that the function is logically constant, that is, as far as users of the class are concerned, the value of the class member is not changed by the function. It is legal to call const functions on const references and through const pointers.